# WebBrowser DocumentCompleted is useless in my case

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

First of all I've repaired WebBrowser and now I see the page correctly in my Windows Form. I folowed this [link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) and referenced it to IE 11.0 so the WebBrowser control in my windows form is a IE11.0 browser instance.

I have this in the constructor of the form:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
```

then the event handler

```
public void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    { 
        txtLoad.Text = (Convert.ToInt32((txtLoad.Text)) + 1).ToString();
        var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
        webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-126").InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

It all starts with a click of a button :

```
void BtnTestClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@"https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=06010154238306490792#AppListPlace");
    }
```

The click invoke does nothing . I tried all methods listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670432/documentcompleted-firing-only-once) and nothing. Why can I see the button on my screen but cannot reference it in code? Why is documentCompleted firing if the button didn't load already? How can I get the button? and click it?

Comment: If you move the invoke to a new button's click event, wait for the page to load then click the button - does it work?

Comment: I've tried that also , IT DOES NOT WORK!

Comment: This is so weird. I mean I see the button right there! Where is it? Is the WebBrowser control that lame? Maybe it's me but I tried the WatiN library and it worked perfectly smooth with the exception that you can't hide the openDialog window so that threw me off because I need it all done in background while I do other stuff on my computer.

Comment: So its unrelated to DocumentCompleted then, rather it seems that there is a problem with the way you are accessing the element.  Visit http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/ in the browser control and check your not in the default IE7 emulation mode

Comment: 1.You!! Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Comment: That's IE11.  Can you give the URL of the in initial page with the button?

Comment: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=06010154238306490792#AppListPlace

Comment: @AlexK, will WebClient click and upload files for me? I don't have to display a webbrowser if it's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=06010154238306490792#AppListPlace");
while (WebBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
         txtLoad.Text = WebBrowser1.ReadyState.ToString();
        Application.DoEvents();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-126").InvokeMember("click");
```

there i a call to the WebBrowserDocumentCompleted event even if the document is not fully loaded.
example: 
lets say that there are 2 script elements inside the page source code:

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
//Here There Is A Call To WebBrowserDocumentCompleted 
<script src="2.js"></script>
//Here There Is A Call To WebBrowserDocumentCompleted
............
body
.............
</html>
//Here There Is A Call To WebBrowserDocumentCompleted
```

the webbrowser is calling this event even after he done loading script/stylesheet - the page is not really fully loaded yet.